# Console control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, console, wpf-controls

This question has been asked in many different ways out there, but I have not found the answer yet. I want to add a control in my WPF window that simulates a console (for writting and reading text, possibly with colors). OK... if there is no control out there already (which is very strange since it's kind of basic), how would I go about building one?

My final goal is to build a Powershell host where I can type commands and get output.

Comment: That question is in the same direction, but not quite the same. I don't want to embed a console window in my WPF. That seems like a hack to me given that WPF has enough firepower to build this natively.

Comment: Kind of frustrating that this is closed, as the other question is very different. Nestor is looking for a control that functions similarly to a console for text display and formatting, the other question wants to embed the default attached console into the application itself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can always make your application a Console application, which gives you a true console.

Otherwise, if you just want to have input and output, typically this can be done via TextBox and/or RichTextBox or the [WPF Document Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx).

Comment: I've read somewhere that a RichTextBox solution is slow. Powershell ISE is written in WPF, but the response is pretty good. I doubt they used RichTextBox...

Comment: @Nestor WPF's isn't bad (like the one in Windows Forms) - I suspect it's built more off the document support, though.

Comment: Powershell ISE uses Microsoft.Windows.Powershell.Gui.Internal.OutputControl, which hosts a Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextViewHost... it'd be great if these were available for use... anyways. Thanks

Comment: Very important feature of console is that it works in circular buffer style, meaning the newest string rewrites the oldest one if current number of lines equals buffer size. It makes console usable for showing last log messages without huge performance impact. Textboxes indeed interpret their content as string and therefore require writing a lot of custom logic. So using them is not a solution if you don't expect the number of lines will always be very small.